# android onSearchRequested() not working

Tags: java, android, search

I cannot seem to get my onSearchRequest() working. I think i have all of the coding correct, would someone be able to check please.

Manifest file

```
<activity android:name="SearchActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".SearchActivity" />
</activity>
```

searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint">
</searchable>
```

SearchActivity.java

```
public class SearchActivity extends android.app.Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if(Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Toast.makeText(this, query,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Method thats called when the button is clicked

```
public void search(View view)
    {
        onSearchRequested();
        Toast.makeText(this, "text",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Can anyone sport any mistakes anywhere??? as from what i can see, it should all be working perfectly.

Comment: I found out what the problem was. I was putting the meta in the wrong activity. It needed to go into the activity which was wanting to use the search function. Not the activity which was processing the search data.